# font loading failed in Service Worker with Offline network

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, service-worker

I have some static HTML pages that I want to store in Service Worker's cache. But when I store all the resources, it works fine but the fonts don't load. Look at the screenshot below it shows me the error.

[image]

I also read other answers on the community for service worker cash, but couldn't find a working solution. I will try the following code but it does not work. Let us know if there are any errors in the code.

```js
const cacheName = `page-cache`;
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                `/`,
                `/index.php`,
            ]).then(() => self.skipWaiting());
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(cache => cache.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch: true}))
            .then(response => { return response || fetch(event.request); })
    );
});
```

Comment: URI of the font file(s)? same-origin or cross-origin?

Comment: same-origin, and i already check font path is ok.!